# How does "berauben" compare to "rauben"?

Tags: word-choice

In conversation, I just said jokingly:

> Nun, das ist ja bedauerlich. Du würdest mich jeglicher Freude am Flirten **berauben**.

I'm wondering how  the use of "rauben" would have compared:

> Nun, das ist ja bedauerlich. Du würdest mir jegliche Freude am Flirten **rauben**.

Leaving aside the different cases required, what difference is there, in terms of nuance, usage, register etc?

Answer (score 4):

*Rauben* puts the thing stolen/robbed into the focus. Naming the stolen item is mandatory, naming the person from whom it is stolen is optional.
*Berauben* concentrates on the victim from which you steal. Naming that person is mandatory, naming the stolen item is optional.

Comment: I see. So if I wanted to say "Why do you do this to **ME**!?", is "berauben" a better choice?

Comment: As a tendency, yes, but it still depends on context and emphasis.